# Tunneling from Dirac material into Schrodinger material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, dirac-equation, quantum-tunneling

When a Dirac material, like graphene or TI, has a connection with a normal metal which Schrodinger equation govern on their carriers, how could we manipulate the tunneling of electron from Dirac side to Schrodinger side or vice verse?

The wave functions of Dirac equation have two components, in the case of graphene, or four components, in the case of pure Bismuth. Whereas the wave functions of normal metals just have one component. So what would happen for boundary condition of wave function??

Comment: Probably, the way to go is to treat everything with the full power of the Dirac equation; you literally can't go wrong there! Maybe there's a 'shortcut', though...

Comment: It seems to me that this question is the same as http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144533/16689 in disguise.